# uncheck 'use default value' on the url_key field in products and categories

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2 with 2 storeviews (Dutch and French).
In products all url keys are in French for the Dutch shop. In categories all url keys are in Dutch for the French storeview.
So I need to uncheck the tickbox 'Use default value' and remove the url key in The Dutch shop and save the product. This causes the the url rewrite is performed again and now the field 'url key' has the correct description. Same methodology for categories in the French storeview.
As I have 18.000 products it is not possible to do this manually. Is there a way to automatically uncheck the tickbox 'use default value' on the url key field in products and categories?